# js files not loaded when using npm http-server

Tags: angularjs, npm, protractor

I've been developing a site for a customer using angularjs as front-end. The tests were written using protractor.
When I run the site using Tomcat 8 in eclipse, the site works as expected, but when the test run using the npm http-server, my service to share data between 2 directives isn't operational. The `service.variable` remains `undefined` all the time.

I've set up a Plunker to represent the structure as much as possible

http://plnkr.co/edit/b49YHoFUlwjFUvsn2Y0C?p=preview

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "private": true,
  "name": "troubleshooting-webapp",
  "description": "Troubleshooting REST Service",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor-http-mock": "^0.2.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6",
    "tmp": "0.0.23"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "npm install",
    "start": "cd src/main &&  http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000",
    "stop": "pkill --signal SIGINT node",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor src/main/webapp/js/tests/protractor-conf.js",
    "preprotractor_debug": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor_debug": "protractor debug src/main/webapp/js/tests/protractor-conf.js"
  }
}
```

protractor-conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 18000,

  specs: [
    'e2e/*.js'
  ],

  mocks: {
        dir: 'mocks'
  },  
  onPrepare: function(){
        require('protractor-http-mock').config = {
            rootDirectory: __dirname, // default value: process.cwd()
            protractorConfig: 'protractor-conf.js' // default value: 'protractor.conf'
        };
  },

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  },

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/',

  framework: 'jasmine',

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000
  }
};
```

Any ideas of why the filterSelection service remains undefined whould be nice.

After some more research, it seems like the mocks aren't loading either.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing any `mocks` in your mock config? Can you show how you are using the mocks?

Comment: @NickTomlin on the same level as the conf file, there's a folder called `mocks` with all the mocks inside it. They are passed using the `mocks: { dir: 'mocks' }` parameter, no?